# Issue with HAProxy and Exchange 2016 with certificate based authentication

Tags: exchange, haproxy

I have an Exchange 2016 as a backend that requires client certificates for accessing OWA and HAProxy as a reverse proxy. When I try to open OWA from Exchange directly everything is fine: I get a certificate prompt and can choose one that I want. But when I do the same through HAProxy I only get certificate prompt for HAProxy and then browser redirects me to Exchange authentication page.
The part of my config is below.

```
frontend fe_exch_443
    bind    x.x.x.x:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt verify optional crt-ignore-err all
acl ssl_connection ssl_fc
    acl path_owa path_beg -i /owa/
    http-request deny if path_check
    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    use_backend bk_exchange_https_owa if path_owa
    default_backend be_exch_443
backend bk_exchange_https_owa
    option httpchk GET /owa/HealthCheck.htm
    http-check expect string 200\ OK
    server  exch        x.x.x.x:443  check ssl verify none maxconn 1000 weight 10 check
```

Could you please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK if bypass HAProxy. Then I think it may be some misconfiguration on HAProxy.

I notice you use “verify optional”, do you want to use client certificate mandatory? Review your configuration based on this blog:
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/ssl-client-certificate-management-at-application-level/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No I want to use client certificate if it is provided because some users must be authenticated by login/password.
I saw that article but it couldn't help me. I think I missed something important in my configuration but I can't find out exactly what.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with HAProxy, maybe someone else here will chime in.